# passing a parameter using JSP include directive

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to pass a parameter to a page using JSP include directive find my code below:

```
<script>
var gTIID

function showPlayerList(pTIID) 
{       

    gTIID=pTIID;
    $("#IdtournamentMessageMain").hide();
    $("#userListFrame").show();

}
</script>

<%@ include file="players_list.jsp" %>
```

How can I pass gTIID to players_list.jsp in the players_list.jsp page gTTID is named tiID (/player_list.htm?tiID=gTIID) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the `<include>` directive, `gTIID` should already be available.

Alternately, you could set them in one of the scopes (request, session, application) and then fetch from the same scope in your other JSP.

Or, you could also use `<jsp:include>` and `<jsp:param>` to achieve this.

Comment: I tried to use <jsp:include> but an error appears : " unknow tag"

Comment: @Saket I can't see how could a js variable be put into request. 
You'd have to use a scriptlet, which would be processed server-side, where client-side variables are not visible. And `<jsp:include>` won't help here either.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to acces `gTIID` in `players_list.jsp`. There's no need to pass it as a parameter, as it's a global-scope defined variable. However, take into account that the variable is only defined and initialized in the including page, not `players.jsp`. If that page is referenced somewhere else, it may be undeclared.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using an hidden input box(id="tidhide") in the "players_list.jsp page initialized to -1 and I set it in the showplayer function, find my snippet code below:

Parent page:

```
function showPlayerList(pTIID) 
{       

    gTIID=pTIID;

    $("#IdtournamentMessageMain").hide();
    $("#tidhide").val(pTIID);
    oTable.fnDraw();
    $("#userListFrame").show(); 

}
```

bye!

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept one answer (may be yours) and remember to upvote helpful posts.